# Shopping list app not adding ,clearing and removing items

Tags: javascript, html, css

[1]Hello,

I am trying to create a shopping list app but I've been troubleshooting it and it is still not working .I dont know what is the wrong code???

Here is my html, css and jquery code in jsfiddle :[shopping list code][1]

```
       [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/rizabarone/hp01kahn/
```

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Answer (score 0):

your code is missing `});`

```
$(function () {
    var add = $('#addItem');
    var newItem = $('#newItem');
    var list = $('#itemList');

    add.on('click', addListItem);
    list.on('click', '.checkbox', tickItem);
    list.on('click', '.delete', deleteItem);
    newItem.on('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            addListItem();
        }
    });
}); // <--------------------- here
```

Comment: Hello Epoch, I added this closing brackets , it looks like the add item button is working but once I hit add item, I dont know where my item goes?... it is not being added at the bottom where it is supposed to